# How to remove the keyword 'figure'?

Tags: graphics

I am writing a slide in Latex, however I wonder if there is a way to remove the word "Figure" when inserting an image in Latex ?

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{picture.jpg}
\caption{Favorite Picture}
\end{figure}
```

*Outuput*:
**Figure:** Favorite Picture
*I want to get this, instead*:
Favorite Picture
How could I do that ?

**EDIT:**
Here is a sample of the code I used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{About me}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=1cm]{picture.png}
\caption{  Favorite Picture}
\end{figure}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for the remark. I edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to chapter 16 of the [beamer package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) documentation, you can use a template to change elements of a presentation design. The options for the caption element are described in section 12.6 of the documentation. According to this, you need `\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{About me}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\caption{  Favorite Picture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide]

Comment: Why the spaces before `Favorite`?

Comment: @egreg --- copied from the MWE; I have no idea why they are there.